# Rational points of finite etale group schemes over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $N$ be an integer and $G \to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Z}[1/N])$ be a finite étale group scheme. I read that, for every prime $p$ not diving $N$ we have :

$$
G(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}) = G(\overline{\mathbf{F}_p})
$$

Why is this true ?

Comment: Because everything in site is constant. In fact, you can even check it's Galois equivariant. More specifically, we may as well base change to the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{N}]$ in $\overline{Q}$, where $G$ is constant. Do you get the idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's merely note that

$$G(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})=G(R)=G_R(R)$$

where $R$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{N}]$ inside of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. I claim that $G_R$ is constant. Indeed, by the standard equivalence between abelian LCC sheaves and finite étale group schemes, we know that $G$ is trivialized on some finite connected étale cover of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{N}])$. But, evidently this is of the form $\mathrm{Spec}(S)$ where $S$ is the ring of integers in some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ unramified outside of $N$. In particular, we see that $S\subseteq R$, and so the result follows.

But, note that we also have that

$$G(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})=G_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})=(G_R)_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$$

and thus we see that $G_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}}$ is constant. Thus, evidently the map

$$G(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})=G_R(R)\to G(\overline{\mathbb{F_p}})$$

is, in fact, the identity once we identify both with the constant group scheme associated to $G$.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! the only point I'm not sure about is why $G(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}) = G(R)$ ? Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: @J.Doe It's finite, so proper :P

Comment: Ah yes ! thank you very much :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis Why does $G$ proper imply that the set of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$-value points are $1-1$ to the set of $R$-value points? Thanks.

Comment: @Sssss Jeeze, this is an old question. You can reduce this to answering the question over a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in which case you can apply the discussion here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109595/an-application-of-valuative-criterion-for-properness

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for your answers. I have studied many things from these old questions.